# Replace values in some rows based on other dataframe mapping

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr, tidyr

I have a table (`d.tab`) with question–answer pairs from a survey. Some of these are single-choice answers, some are multiple-choice. I want to look up the text value of the single-choice answer from its numerical value. For that, I have a lookup table (`d.lookup`).

I tried to `merge` these, but it's a bit ugly, since I now have to filter out all the rows where `value != answer_id`. Is there a prettier way of doing this, possibly using `plyr` or `dplyr` or `tidyr`?

```
tab = '
question_id question_type   subject value
1   single-choice   1   1
2   multiple-choice 1   2
3   single-choice   1   2
1   single-choice   2   2
2   multiple-choice 2   3,4
3   single-choice   2   2
'

lookup = '
question_id answer_id   answer_text
1   1   female
1   2   male
3   1   no
3   2   yes
'

d.tab = read.table(text = tab, header = TRUE)
d.lookup = read.table(text = lookup, header = TRUE)

merge(d.tab, d.lookup, by = "question_id", all.x = TRUE)
```

I don't want to do anything with `multiple-choice` rows, but simply update the original dataframe to replace `value` with the actual text from `d.tab`'s `answer_text` if the `answer_id`s match the `value`.

I know I can do:

```
merge(d.tab, d.lookup, by.x = c("question_id", "value"), by.y = c("question_id", "answer_id"), all.x = TRUE)
```

But this gives me a new column `answer_text` with the original `value` still there, which I don't need.

Comment: You can merge by several columns that may even have different names. It is correct that you actually only want to merge for single-choice answers? Otherwise, the row with `3,4` will be a bit tricky.

Comment: Yes, I don't want to do anything with multiple-choice rows. These are just there for showing that I need to only replace a subset of values.

Comment: See updated question; I just noticed I can do this multi-key merge, but it doesn't quite achieve what I need.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have the correct call of `merge()` in your question. All that is left is that you filter for the rows with single-choice answers and select all the columns except `value`. Using dplyr, this can be done as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
filter(d.tab, question_type == "single-choice") %>%
  mutate(value = as.numeric(as.character(value))) %>%
  merge(d.lookup, by.x = c("question_id", "value"),
        by.y = c("question_id", "answer_id")) %>%
  select(-value)
```

The second line contains the explicit conversion of the factor variable `value` to numeric. This is important, because conversion of factors to numeric can lead to weird results. I'll add a few lines regarding this topic below.

Note that `dplyr` also comes with its own functions to replace merge. In case your table is large, you will notice that these are more efficient. Using `left_join` from `dplyr` the solution reads:

```
library(dplyr)
filter(d.tab, question_type == "single-choice") %>%
  mutate(value = as.numeric(as.character(value))) %>%
  left_join(d.lookup,
            by = c("question_id" = "question_id",
                   "value" = "answer_id")) %>%
  select(-value)
```

So here comes the comment regarding factors that I promised. The issue with factors is that they are actually integers, where each integer value has a label associated with it. When you naively convert the factors to numeric with `as.numeric()`, you will get the integer that is associated with the label. You will almost certainly run into this problem with your data and here is why.

I create a factor variable that mimicks your data:

```
values <- factor(c("1", "2", "3,4", "3", "4"))
```

Now I throw away the third value (`"3,4"`) and convert to numeric:

```
as.numeric(values[-3])
## [1] 1 2 3 5
```

This is probably not what you expected. The reason is that the numbers 1 to 5 were associated to the five levels that we defined above. If you want to get the numbers that match the labels, you need to first convert to character:

```
as.numeric(as.character(values[-3]))
## [1] 1 2 3 4
```

So, even though `merge()` does the conversion of the factors to numeric somewhere, I wouldn't rely on it doing it in the way you want. Therefore, you should do the conversion explicitly.

Comment: That's some great advice, thanks a lot! Now, I have a slight variation of the problem. Let's say I had another question type `likert`, and a lookup table with the only columns `answer_id` and `answer_text` (e.g. answer 1 meaning "strongly disagree", 2 meaning "disagree" etc.). How would I go about replacing that subset of my original data frame's values (assuming I've kept the original column `value` intact)? When I do a merge here, I get `answer_text.x`and `answer_text.y` columns, the former being still NA for the rows where I would've replaced it.

Comment: Wouldn't you just merge by `value` and `answer_id`. There is nothing wrong, if there are many matches in `d.tab`. The matching line from the lookup table will simply be merged into `d.tab` as many time as it is needed. Or was your question about something else?

Comment: Yes, I could do this merge, but let's say I already did the other merge before, so I already have an `answer_text` column that contains `NA` values for the rows where the `question_type` is `likert`. If I then do another merge, I *already* have an `answer_text` column, and I then get `answer_text.x` and `answer_text.y` in my result. If this is a bit hard to image without data—which I can understand—I could post a new question, of course :)

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution with *data.table*:

```
library(data.table)

# converting to datatables & setting the 'answer_id' to character
setDT(d.tab)
setDT(d.lookup)[, answer_id := as.character(answer_id)]

# join 'd.tab' with 'd.lookup' and update 'value' by reference
d.tab[d.lookup, value := answer_text, on = c("question_id", "value"="answer_id")]
```

which gives:

```
   question_id   question_type subject  value
1:           1   single-choice       1 female
2:           2 multiple-choice       1      2
3:           3   single-choice       1    yes
4:           1   single-choice       2   male
5:           2 multiple-choice       2    3,4
6:           3   single-choice       2    yes
```

---

As already mentioned by @Stibu, it is probably better to split rows with multiple values. An example with the `cSplit` function from the *splitstackshape* package:

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(d.tab, "value", sep=",", 
       direction="long", 
       type.convert = FALSE)[d.lookup, 
                             value := answer_text, 
                             on = c("question_id", "value"="answer_id")]

# or everything in 'data.table'
d.tab[, lapply(.SD, function(x) unlist(tstrsplit(x, ','))), setdiff(names(d.tab),"value")
      ][d.lookup, value := answer_text, on = c("question_id", "value"="answer_id")][]
```

which both give:

```
   question_id   question_type subject  value
1:           1   single-choice       1 female
2:           2 multiple-choice       1      2
3:           3   single-choice       1    yes
4:           1   single-choice       2   male
5:           2 multiple-choice       2      3
6:           2 multiple-choice       2      4
7:           3   single-choice       2    yes
```

Comment: That looks very clean, thanks! (Why again are there a million solutions to achieving one thing in R?)